# PM2 with mercurial repo in deployment

Tags: deployment, mercurial, pm2

I have a mercurial repository in bitbucket.org and I want to use it in deployment with pm2.
My deploy section is:

```
deploy : {
    production : {
      user : "dimon",
      host : "app.mysite.com",
      ref  : "origin/master",
      repo : "hg@bitbucket.org:mylogin/myrepo",
      path : "/var/www/test_prod",
      "post-deploy" : "npm install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json --env production"
    }
  }
```

When I run deploy I get a error:

```
  ○ cloning hg@bitbucket.org:mylogin/myrepo
Cloning into '/var/www/test_prod/source'...
conq: not a git repository.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I also tried "mercurial@bitbucket.org:mylogin/myrepo" string, without success.
How to set mercurial repository correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to maintainers, pm2 deploy works only with git now.
[GitHub](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2683)